# If loop execution

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

In the code below,

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int k,sum;
    for(k=7;k>=0;sum=k--)
        printf("%d \n",sum);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
0
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

I want to know how this loop executes and why isn't printing 0 in the last?

Comment: Pick some C book and read loops.

Comment: I've read and tried this. I couldn't understand How this works.

Comment: @Teja713..Try to trace the logic

Comment: Because it first store `1` to `sum` and the decrease to `0`. Try `--k`.

Comment: @yannis; How it store `1` to `sum` ?

Comment: @haccks I'm pretty much saying the same with Basic(see answer). The question was *why isn't printing 0 in the last?*

Answer (score 5):

On first iteration `sum` is uninitialized. It has **indeterminate** value.

#### C11: 6.7.9 Initialization:

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is
> **indeterminate**.

Section 6.3.2.1 says that the behavior is **undefined** in this case.

Comment: Yet lvalue conversion has undefined behaviour on uninitialized values that are potentially of `register` storage.

Comment: @KerrekSB; Standard says that it should be of `register` storage ?

Comment: Only that it "could have `register` storage", I think.

Answer (score 2):

In short, the `sum` variable is updated to be the same as `k`. After that update, `k` is decremented by 1 and then the loop runs

What that means is...

First loop, `sum` is uninitialised (hence the first `0`)

the last time the loop runs, `sum` is set to `k` (1), k is decremented to 0. The loop runs. The condition is tested so the loop exits.

It all comes down the this: `sum=k--`. If you were to do `sum=--k`, k would be decremented *before* its value is assigned to sum.

Comment: *`sum` is uninitialised (hence the first `0`)*:  How you concluded that?  *If you were to do `sum=--k`, k would be decremented before its value is assigned to sum.*: How would this help to prevent the program to print `0` at first place?

Comment: @haccks the `Increment` part of the `for` runs at the end of the loop. Thus when the loop runs, sum hasn't been explicitly set and prints `0`

Answer (score 1):

Your program has undefined behaviour, since it is reading from an uninitialized variable in the first round of the loop (cf. C11 6.3.2.1/2).

Answer (score 1):

Following code :

```
for(k =7; k >= 0; sum = k--)
   //your code here printf("%d \n",sum);
```

can be expanded as:

```
k=7;
for(; k >= 0; ){
   //your code here printf("%d \n",sum);
   sum = k--;
}
```

In first run `sum` is uninitialized so your program have undefined behavior.

Comment: The increment or the decrement part is executed on every iteration after the loop body execution completes , the initialization part is executed only once first time the loop executes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 #include<stdio.h>
     int main()
      {
     int k=7,sum;
      for(sum=k=7;k>=0;sum=--k)

       printf("%d \n",sum);
      return 0;
       }
```

The loop starts by taking the initial value of the sum which in this case is by default equal to zero as a result the first iteration displays 0 however on the second iteration init of sum takes place and it starts from 7 to onward 0

Answer (score 0):

When k=1 then value of k is assigned to sum and it gets decremented to 0 . Thus sum = 1 and k = 0.
Now k=0 and as per the loop condition k>=0 is true. So it enters into loop body and prints value of sum as 1 . Now value of k is get assigned to sum and k decrements . Thus sum = 0 and  k = -1 . But -1>=0 is false and loop execution stops .
Hence program is not printing 0 in the last.